# i want to implement code while updating the product list if item's productQuantity is null or blank then it will toast a message

Tags: android

```
    OrderListModel lOrderListModel = new OrderListModel();

    lOrderListModel.productNumber = lModel.ProductNumber;
    lOrderListModel.productImage = lModel.productImage;
    lOrderListModel.productName = lModel.productName;
    lOrderListModel.productPrice = lModel.productPrice;
    lOrderListModel.productCategory = lModel.productCategory;
    lOrderListModel.userName = username;
    lOrderListModel.productQuantity = mEdQuanity.getText().toString();
```

//i want to add a toast if productQuantity in blank or null.

```
    double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(lModel.productPrice) * Double.parseDouble(mEdQuanity.getText().toString());
    lOrderListModel.productTotalPrice = "" + totalPrice;
    String orderId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String userId = SharePref.getInstance(QuantityScreen.this).getLoginUserId();
    updateItemCount();
    datasource.addOrder(orderId, userId, lOrderListModel);
    Toast.makeText(QuantityScreen.this, R.string.order_added_suc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

//on click ADD button this will display a toast or an error message to input value

```
private void updateItemCount() {
    String oldOrderCount = SharePref.getInstance(QuantityScreen.this).getOrderCount();
    if (!oldOrderCount.equals("")) {
        SharePref.getInstance(QuantityScreen.this).saveOrderCount("" + (Integer.parseInt(oldOrderCount) + Integer.parseInt(mEdQuanity.getText().toString())));
    } else {
        SharePref.getInstance(QuantityScreen.this).saveOrderCount("" + Integer.parseInt(mEdQuanity.getText().toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(productQuantity)) {
            //show Toast
        } else {
           //do whatever you wanted to
        }
```